# Mysql query in java

Tags: java, mysql, rest, netbeans

I have a service  rest from database generated in netbeans. This creates entity classes for each table .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", 
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findById", 
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByName", 
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.name = :name"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByTelephone", 
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.telephone = :telephone"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByYear", 
                query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.year = :year")})

public class Users implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "telephone")
    private Integer telephone;
    @Column(name = "year")
    private Integer year;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(Integer telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Users)) {
            return false;
        }
        Users other = (Users) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) 
                || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "glee.Users[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
```

How I can query the db with this class from another? ? 
For example do a select : select `name` from bb.users;
and save it in an array eg
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `@NamedQuery(name,query)` annotation is used to hard code the Queries
>   into the Persistence class. You can retrieve the `query` using the
>   `name` attribute specified.
>
> When using hibernate session, you can use [**getNamedQuery**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#getNamedQuery%28java.lang.String%29) to
>   get the query.
>
> When used with [**EntityManager**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) you can use
>   [**createNamedQuery**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

Both of this will retrieve the query and and you can execute the query with basic query operations.

> List Users =
>   session.getNamedQuery("Users.findById").setParameter("id",
>   "1").list();

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try to apply it and tell you if I served. I hope so!